# Spring: java: package javax.validation.constraints does not exist

Tags: java, spring, maven

I already have this dependency in my pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And have refreshed Maven and already restarted IntelliJ but always get this error
`java: package javax.validation.constraints does not exist`

It cannot find this package for some reason.
But this error occurs only when I try to compile.

In my Entity class I imported `import javax.validation.constraints.Size;`

and want to add an annotation to a column for example:

```
@Size(min = 1)
private String name;
```

or

```
@DecimalMin("0.01")
private BigDecimal amount;
```

But always I get the problem with the validation package.

There is no error message in the IDE, the error appears when I run.

Comment: If you compile the project throw terminal mvn clean `spring-boot:repackage`, do you get the same resul?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I used it like this in my Spring app and it worked.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Beware that now it's jakarta.validation-api

Answer (score 41):

**Validation Starter no longer included in web starters** from the Spring Boot version 2.3 : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#validation-starter-no-longer-included-in-web-starters

you should add it yourself.

Answer (score 17):

[Jakarta Bean Validation API](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.validation/jakarta.validation-api) is the recommended dependency to import and solve this issue:

#### Maven

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

#### Gradle

```
implementation 'jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:2.0.2'
```

Comment: I tested adding this dependency but it didn't seem to resolve my problem unfortunately.

Comment: After reviewing this further it seems like the javax.validation dependency is resolved in version '2.0.2' but not in '3.0.2'

Comment: @hreinn, to get validation-api in version 3.0.2 use the dependency as in the [link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.validation/jakarta.validation-api/3.0.2). If the dependency is not resolving try to force the project build or remove the dependency in your local maven repository because it may be corrupted and then run the build again.

Comment: In my case using your 3.0.2 dependency from your link did not seem to help, but downgrading to 2.0.2 did seem to.

Answer (score 7):

For gradle users add this dependency to build.gradle file:

```
implementation 'javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final'
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to change your imports from

`javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;`

to

`import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;`